# How to Back Up wordpress.org?

Tags: database, wordpress, wordpress-theming, backup

I need help understanding the ins and outs of backing up WordPress. What is the best method to backup WordPress.org files and database? Manually through phpmyadmin -or- a backup plugin?

.

Can backups done MANUALLY result in corrupted backups? Can backups from PLUGINS result in corrupted backups?

Does backup plugins make your website run slower?

Is UpdraftPlus any good? Any drawbacks?

.

I understand that it is necessary to backup the WordPress DATABASE, but why is it necessary to back up WordPress FILES? Is it for people who make changes to the PHP files within the WordPress dashboard?

Do I need to back up wordpress FILES if I make changes to my theme in a local server then upload to host?

Answer (score 0):

The `Duplicator Plugin` gives WordPress administrators the ability to migrate, copy or clone a site from one location to another. The plugin also serves as a simple backup utility. The Duplicator supports both serialized and base64 serialized string replacement. If you need to move WordPress or backup WordPress this plugin can help simplify the process.

use this plugin
https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/